# Vue.js -- How do you display image using a URL in an array of an object within an array?

Tags: image, vue.js

Good afternoon!

I am working on a project that has displaying images of the national parks. I have called the National Parks api and get back an array of all the national parks in the database. But I am trying to display the image using the URL provided that is currently embedded in the object in an array of objects marked 'images'.
[images-array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35rHY.png)
This is my code in Vue.js:

```xml
<template>
  <ul class="list">
    <li v-for="park in parks" :key="park.parkCode" >
      <img :src="park.images[0].url"/>
      <h4>{{park.name}}</h4>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

But every time I run it, I get this error...

Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"

I know it is probably something stupid simple, but my brain can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share code for the rest of your component?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the response.
If park object includes images like

```js
{   ...,  "images" : ['image.png','image2.png], ...}
```

you should try `park.images[0]`

if it looks like

```js
{   ...,  "images" : [{'url':'image.png'},{'url':'image2.png'}], ...}
```

it should be ok.

Comment: images: Array(4)
0:
altText: "Large puffy clouds dot a brilliant blue sky as wave crash against the rocky coastline of Acadia."
caption: "Millions of people come to Acadia for our distinctive rocky coastline."
credit: "NPS / Kristi Rugg"
title: "Acadia's rocky coastline"
url: "https://www.nps.gov/common/uploads/structured_data/3C7B45AE-1DD8-B71B-0B7EE131C7DFC2F5.jpg"

Comment: This is what it looks like.